# Scatterplot draws points in the middle

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I have a problem with Scatterplot in ggplot2. I do not know why all the points are drawn center, tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```
ggplot(TD, aes(x="Goals total", y="Assists", group=Position)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape=Position, color=Position)) 

> TD
# A tibble: 9 x 3
  Position `Goals total` Assists
    <fctr>         <dbl>   <dbl>
1      RCB             0       0
2      RCB             0       1
3      RCB             3       1
4       RB             0       0
5       RB             2       1
6       RB             0       0
7       CF             0       0
8       CF             1       0
9       CF             6       0
```

[image]

Comment: You need to either use all strings or all expressions. If you are using strings change `aes` to `aes_string` and change to `group = "Position"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`aes` does not take strings. So when you pass `x = "Goals total"` to `aes` it is treating that as if the values of `x` are all `"Goals total"` (which is why the string `"Goals total"` is actually a tick mark on the `x-axis` in your plot rather than the axis name). So if you wanted to continue using it you could do:

```
ggplot(TD, aes(x=`Goals total`, y=Assists, group=Position)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape=Position, color=Position))
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use all strings with `aes_string`:

```
ggplot(TD, aes_string(x="`Goals total`", y="Assists", group="Position")) +
  geom_point(aes(shape=Position, color=Position))
```

Also another idea to consider would be to not use spaces in your variable names. With them, you have to use ` to access them as expressions.